# jqGrid 4.8.0 - How to get cell type or cell value using jsonmap

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I'm trying to get a cell value from `onSelectRow` event.

I can achieve that using:

```
celValue = $('#jqGrid').jqGrid ('getCell', rowid, 'id');
```

Two question:

1. Is there a way to get it by using `'jsonmap'`, and not `'name'`?
2. Is there a way to get the type of the cell?  (date, number, integer etc')

Thanks,

Tal.

Comment: Which `datatype` you use in the real project? (`"local"`, `"json"`, ...) If you use remote datatype (`"json"` or `"xml"`) then it could be good to know whether you use `loadonce: true` or not. One more question. I wrote you about the possibility to use `template` in `colModel`. Do you plan to change `colModel` to use it? You second question can be very easy solved if you would use column templates.

Comment: Thanks,  I use json, and have not set the loadonce.  I didn't switch yet to templates (on my plans) but if that's the only way to achieve that, than I will asap :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first find the index of the column from which you want to get the data. You can use the code like

```js
var $grid = $("#jqGrid"), colModel = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"), cm, i,
    iCol = -1, l = colModel.length, propName = "jsonmap", propVal = "start_time", val;

for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    cm = colModel[i];
    if (cm[propName] === propVal) {
        iCol = i;
        break;
    }
}
if (iCol >= 0) {
    val = $grid.jqGrid("getCell", rowid, iCol);
}
```

The above code search the index `iCol` of the column which has `propVal` (`"start_time"`) in the property `propName` (`"jsonmap"`). The first column with the property will be used as option of `getCell`.

In the same way you can search for the column which has specific `formatter`. I would recommend you to use column templates in `colModel`. If you defines `cmTemplate`

```
$.extend(true, $.jgrid, {
    cmTemplate: {
        dateType: {
            sorttype: "date", edittype: "date", formatter: "date",
            formatoptions: { srcformat: "U/1000", newformat: "m/d/Y H:i:s" },
            searchoptions: { sopt: [ "eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge" ] },
            editoptions: { sopt: [ "eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge" ] },
            searchrules: { date: true }
        }
    }
});
```

after that you can use `template: "dateType"` property in `colModel`. In the way you can define many different types which all use the same formatter. Moreover you will have really readable `colModel` which can be very easy maintained. You can include properties like `width` which you can *overwrite* in `colModel`. In the way you can specify more better default values for some properties, but you can hold still the same flexibility like before. If I examine the code of [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mrfvsyc2/1/) which you posted I think that column templates would be very good for you.

Comment: Thanks Oleg,  it can get up to a 1000 columns fields in my ColModel. Is iteration is the only way? I can have a workaround if I'll know the field type. Can i know the field type without doing an iteration?

Comment: @Tal: It's **very bad idea** to use `colModel` with 1000 columns. It you don't need some columns you should remove there from `colModel` instead of making there `hidden`. Hidden columns will be still placed on the page and makes the working of the web browser more slowly. You can just measure the time of loading the grid. By the way jqGrid look through the columns of the `colModel` many times. So if you would include the code which I posted in your code you will see no performance difference. One more remark: more columns in the grid is much more expensive for the web browser as more rows.

Comment: I see.  I could have remove the hidden from the ColModel, but then how will I use the column chooser?

Comment: @Tal: You can hold columns which could be displayed to the user, but I don't believe that `columnCooser` will be able to display the user 1000 columns. I think that the results will be unacceptable for the user. Moreover you should consider to use `loadonce: true` scenario if you have less as 10000 of rows in the grid. It could improve the performance. You can consider to save some information as JavaScript objects instead of DOM objects. Hidden DOM elements are expensive, but `userData` or any variable with 1000 elements are must more quickly in access. **How many rows you have totally?**

Comment: I have couple of million rows. I must use tge paging and it works great. Maybe I need to reload and unload the colmodel before and after the columnchooser?

Comment: How many columns you need to display at once? I think that recreating of the grid (and `colModel`) seems be good in your case.

Comment: I have up to 10-20.  Your idea of recreational of the grid with each column selection might be the right thing to do, I'll just need to implement the column chooser myself :-(

Comment: Can I change the colModel AFTER the grid was load? This way I can implement the columnchooser as an independent function.